# nginx-clojure installation and configuration on ubuntu

Tags: nginx

I used below link to install nginx-clojure but not able to install it properly.

http://nginx-clojure.github.io/installation.html

Can anyone help me out to achieve this?

Comment: Where do you stuck at installation?

Comment: You should add more info - where did you get stuck, what error(s) are you getting, etc.

Comment: I downloaded nginx-clojure-0.4.5.tar.gz file and untar it and replaced this  nginx-linux-x64 file to nginx(as described it in above link). What should i do now to use it?

Comment: These docs shoud be useful 1) http://nginx-clojure.github.io/quickstart.html  2) http://nginx-clojure.github.io/configuration.html  3) https://github.com/nginx-clojure/nginx-clojure/tree/master/example-projects/clojure-web-example